# Why does Luffy's Conqueror Haki at Marineford not work on everyone?

Tags: one-piece

When Luffy used Conqueror's Haki at Marineford, not all the people there fell down. I noticed that only the powerful ones like Whitebeard, Sengoku, Garp, Ace etc. were left standing. While the weaker soldiers as well as pirates fell down.

Why were only the weaker people affected ?

Comment: If you want to dispute your question's closure, you need to actually edit it to explain the difference. Making a worthless edit that only adds an unnecessary space, and explaining your objection in the edit summary, isn't going to help. It's worth noting that the linked question seems to cover Haki in general, not just Armament Haki; if you think that it doesn't cover Conqueror's Haki, and/or that the answer would somehow be different for Conqueror's Haki, you need to edit the question *properly* to explain why.

Comment: That's literally how conqueror's haki works: it's a big sign that says "You must be at least this tall to fight against me".